# How can we use NEW.columns of Triggers as part in INSERT - SELECT WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql

I have created a LOCAL Support Ticketing Application that will allow user Create Tickets and submit to Support Department. Every created ticket broadcast to all agents in the Support Department. So I decided to use MySQL TRIGGER - AFTER INSERT for capturing every incoming ticket of my tickets table and, I use INSERT...SELECT to populate the new ticket and Support Department and there Agents.

Here is my Trigger below, and Why it doesn't insert anything. I think I don't get the value of NEW.PK_tickets and NEW.FK_users.

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `support`$$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `trsample`$$

CREATE
/*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */
TRIGGER `trtickets` AFTER INSERT ON `tickets` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

/** (start) push all notification **/
INSERT INTO `notifications`(`TRX`,`from`,`to`,`content`, `type`,`created_at`)
SELECT DISTINCT
    `tickets`.`PK_tickets`, `tickets`.`FK_users`, `users_departments`.`FK_users`, `tickets`.`subject`, 'TIX', `tickets`.`created_at`
FROM `tickets`

JOIN (
    SELECT `tickets_from`.`FK_tickets`,`tickets_from`.`FK_departments` FROM `tickets_from`
    UNION DISTINCT
    SELECT `tickets_to`.`FK_tickets`,`tickets_to`.`FK_departments` FROM `tickets_to` ) j1
ON j1.`FK_tickets` = `tickets`.`PK_tickets`

JOIN `users_departments`
ON `users_departments`.`FK_departments` = j1.`FK_departments`

WHERE `tickets`.`PK_tickets` = NEW.PK_tickets AND `users_departments`.`FK_users` <> NEW.FK_users;
/** (end) push all notification **/

END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

to double check my SQL Query I use Stored Procedure, and It runs

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `support`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `spnottickets`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spnottickets`(IN IN_PK_tickets INT, IN IN_FK_users INT)
BEGIN

/** (start) push all notification **/
INSERT INTO `notifications`(`TRX`,`from`,`to`,`content`, `type`,`created_at`)
SELECT DISTINCT
    `tickets`.`PK_tickets`, `tickets`.`FK_users`, `users_departments`.`FK_users`, `tickets`.`subject`, 'TIX', `tickets`.`created_at`
FROM `tickets`

JOIN (
    SELECT `tickets_from`.`FK_tickets`,`tickets_from`.`FK_departments` FROM `tickets_from`
    UNION DISTINCT
    SELECT `tickets_to`.`FK_tickets`,`tickets_to`.`FK_departments` FROM `tickets_to` ) j1
ON j1.`FK_tickets` = `tickets`.`PK_tickets`

JOIN `users_departments`
ON `users_departments`.`FK_departments` = j1.`FK_departments`

WHERE `tickets`.`PK_tickets` = IN_PK_tickets AND `users_departments`.`FK_users` <> IN_FK_users;
/** (end) push all notification **/

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Can we use NEW.columns as part of our WHERE clause?

Comment: Pretty heavy SQL question - might have more luck at https://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I think you can use OLD.field and NEW.field in any part of a trigger, except a OLD.field on a INSERT, or NEW.field on a DELETE. Have you tried it? If you have any problem, please update your question with the error itself.

Comment: Is there any `BEFORE INSERT` trigger on the same table? The MySQL doc claims: `An AFTER trigger is executed only if any BEFORE triggers and the row operation execute successfully`  Other than that, yes, the NEW.columns can be used with WHERE. The docs also have a very basic example using a NEW.col within a WHERE clause.

Comment: There is no OLD row in on INSERT trigger

Comment: When i do this to my WHERE CLAUSE `WHERE tickets.PK_tickets = 135 AND users_departments.FK_users <> 1;` Putting Fixed Value it runs and inserted. But I want to Use NEW.Column.